# Hartshorne's definition of structure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Hartshorne at page $70$ defines the structure sheaf on Spec $A$. The elements of $\mathcal O_{\textrm{Spec}A}(U)$ are particular functions $s:U\longrightarrow\coprod_{p\in U}A_p$. With the symbol  $\coprod_{p\in U}$ I think he means the coproduct in the category of commutative rings, but in can't figure out what precisely is $\coprod_{p\in U}A_p$ in this case. It is the direct sum of the rings $A_p$? Does the coproduct always exist in the category of commutative rings?

Comment: disjoint union, or coproduct in the category of sets.

Comment: Incidentally, coproducts do exist in $\mathbf{CRing}$, and finite coproducts are tensor products.

Comment: Since $s(p) \in A_p$ is included into the definition, you could also write $s \in \prod_{p \in U} A_p$ directly. The idea is that a regular function consists of a bunch of its stalks, here localizations of $A$, but in order to get something interesting we have to impose a compatiblity condition between them: Locally these stalks are induced by a single fraction. This summarizes the definition of the structure sheaf. I wouldn't write $\coprod_p A_p$, since this is only confusing (see also Zhen's comment and the existence of this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just the disjoint union of the underlying sets. The elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}A}(U)$ are functions on $U$ whose value at the point $\mathfrak{p}$ is an element of the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$

Comment: Disjoint union of *the underlying* sets. It is funny that forgetful functors are exactly those functors which are forgotten by most mathematicians (outside of category theory) ...